# YouTube Data API: Server won't return ProcessingProgress

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-data-api

Before anyone complains: Yes I've searched on google and stackoverflow, but wasn't successfull.

So: I can upload videos, update them via snippets etc without any problems. But when I try to receive the current processing progress (while the video is still processing) I can't access `getProcessingDetails().getProcessingProgress()` because it's null.

Here's my code:

```
YouTube.Videos.List resp = YouTubeHandler.youtube.videos().list("processingDetails");
resp.setId(videoID);
resp.setOauthToken(Authenticator.getCredential(Authenticator.getSelectedAccount()).getAccessToken());
VideoListResponse vidResp = resp.execute();
for(String s : vidResp.getItems().get(0).getProcessingDetails().keySet()){
   System.out.println(s + ": " + vidResp.getItems().get(0).getProcessingDetails().get(s));
}
System.out.println(vidResp.getItems().get(0).getProcessingDetails().getProcessingProgress());
```

This is the result from the console:

```
editorSuggestionsAvailability: inProgress
fileDetailsAvailability: available
processingIssuesAvailability: available
processingStatus: processing
tagSuggestionsAvailability: inProgress
thumbnailsAvailability: inProgress
null
```

I'm using JAVA 7 and YouTube Data API v3 1.18.0 and rev107.

Thanks for reading / helping! :)

Comment: At `for(String s : vidResp.getItems().get(0)...` how do you know your query returned any data?  The symptom seems to indicate you got an empty response back and didn't check for that possibility.

Comment: The system.print inside the for-loop prints all values properly. Only the one outisde the loop returns null (null-checks and accessing values inside the processingprogress-object also return true / throw NPEs) (I'm trying to solve this for weeks now and tested a lot of possible things)

Comment: You may have a race condition (processing ended before you reached the final statement) or a bug in the API.  You'll probably get more help on a Google Youtube API forum.

Comment: Well the video is always completely uploaded and processed. :/ But thanks. I think it's a bug too, but who knows.